# Trouble retrieving related data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble retrieving the `StateInt` value from the `States` table based on the value stored in the `AppTenantState` column in the `Applications` table.

I'm using one DropDownList to allow the Renter and if applicable Tenant to use a single DropDownList to select the State they reside in. That's were the States table comes in to play. I only have one "StateId" value in the Applications Table which is the State the Renter resides in. I added a field called AppTenantState to hold the StateId value for the Tenant (if applicable) in the AppTenantState field.

I can get the value I need to use the SQL query below, but I'm not sure how to retrieve that value along with the data I need to retrieve in the `Details` action method:

```
SELECT StateInt 
FROM States 
INNER JOIN Applications ON States.StateId = Applications.AppTenantState 
WHERE ApplicationId = 13;
```

Please help! :( I have my code below. Thank you in advance!

Application model class:

```
public class Application
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string AppFirstName { get; set; }
    public string AppLastName { get; set; }
    public string AppAddress { get; set; }
    public string AppCity { get; set; }
    public string AppZipCode { get; set; }

    public string AppTenantFirstName { get; set; }
    public string AppTenantLastName { get; set; }
    public string AppTenantAddress { get; set; }
    public string AppTenantCity { get; set; }
    public int? AppTenantState { get; set; }
    public string AppTenantZipCode { get; set; }

    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
}
```

`State` model class:

```
public class State
{
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string StateInt { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; }
}
```

`ApplicationDetailsByIdViewModel` view model class:

```
public class ApplicationDetailsByIdViewModel
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public Application Applications { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API configuration:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Begin Application Database Table Schema
        builder.Entity<Application>()
            .HasKey(a => a.ApplicationId);

        builder.Entity<Application>()
            .Property(a => a.AppFirstName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(25)")
            .HasMaxLength(25)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Entity<Application>()
            .Property(a => a.AppLastName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(25)")
            .HasMaxLength(25)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Entity<Application>()
            .Property(a => a.AppAddress)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Entity<Application>()
            .Property(a => a.AppCity)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Entity<Application>()
            .Property(a => a.AppZipCode)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(5)")
            .HasMaxLength(5)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Entity<Application>()
            .Property(a => a.AppTenantFirstName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(25)")
            .HasMaxLength(25)
            .IsRequired(required: false);

        builder.Entity<Application>()
            .Property(a => a.AppTenantLastName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(25)")
            .HasMaxLength(25)
            .IsRequired(required: false);

        builder.Entity<Application>()
            .Property(a => a.AppTenantAddress)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired(required: false);

        builder.Entity<Application>()
            .Property(a => a.AppTenantCity)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired(required: false);

        builder.Entity<Application>()
            .Property(a => a.AppTenantState)
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsRequired(required: false);

        builder.Entity<Application>()
            .Property(a => a.AppTenantZipCode)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(5)")
            .HasMaxLength(5)
            .IsRequired(required: false);

        // Begin One-To-Many Relationship Between Application and State
        builder.Entity<Application>()
            .HasOne(a => a.State)
            .WithMany(s => s.Applications)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.StateId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        // End Application Database Table Schema



        // Begin State Database Table Schema
        builder.Entity<State>()
            .HasKey(s => s.StateId);

        builder.Entity<State>()
            .Property(s => s.StateInt)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(2)")
            .HasMaxLength(2)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Entity<State>()
            .Property(s => s.StateName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();
        // End State Database Table Schema
    }
}
```

`ApplicationController`:

```
public class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public ApplicationController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    // GET: /Applications
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Application> objList = _db.Applications;
        return View(objList);
    }

    // GET: /Details/id
    public IActionResult Details(int? applicationId)
    {
        if (applicationId == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var model = new ApplicationDetailsByIdViewModel
        {
            Applications = _db.Applications
                              .Include(s => s.State)
                              .FirstOrDefault(r => r.ApplicationId == applicationId)
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    // GET: /Details/id
    public IActionResult Delete(int? applicationId)
    {
        if (applicationId == null || applicationId == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Application applicationObj = _db.Applications.Include(s => s.State).FirstOrDefault(a=> a.ApplicationId == applicationId);
        
        if (applicationObj == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(applicationObj);
    }

    [HttpPost,ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult DeletePost(int? applicationId)
    {
        var applicationObj = _db.Applications.Find(applicationId);

        if (applicationObj == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _db.Applications.Remove(applicationObj);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Details Razor page:

```
<div class="details">
    <div class="fullname">
        <span class="details-span">Full Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fullname-value">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Applications.AppFirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Applications.AppLastName)
    </div>

    <div class="address">
        <span class="details-span">Address</span>
    </div>
    <div class="address-value">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Applications.AppAddress), @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Applications.AppCity), @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Applications.State.StateInt) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Applications.AppZipCode)
    </div>

    <div class="tenantfullname">
        <span class="details-span">Name of Co-Tenant</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tenantfullname-value">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Applications.AppTenantFirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Applications.AppTenantLastName)
    </div>

    <div class="tenantaddress">
        <span class="details-span">Current Address</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tenantaddress-value">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Applications.AppTenantAddress) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Applications.AppTenantCity) @(Model.Applications.AppTenantState) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Applications.AppTenantZipCode)
    </div>
</div>
```

The following line below in the `Details` page is what I'm having trouble with. It retrieves the int value of `AppTenantState` such as "38" instead of displaying the `StateInt` value for "38" which would be OH.

```
@(Model.Applications.AppTenantState)
```

**Sample Application Table Data**

| ApplicationId | AppTenantState | StateId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 33 |
| 2 | 34 | 38 |
| 3 | 37 | 37 |
| 4 | 40 | 40 |

**Sample State Table Data**

| StateId | StateInt | StateName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | OH | Ohio |
| 34 | WV | West Virginia |
| 37 | PA | Pennsylvania |
| 40 | MI | Michigan |

Comment: "AppTenantState to hold the StateId value for the Tenant (if applicable) in the AppTenantState field." What do you mean? I am not clear about the problem you meet now. Can you give an example ?

Comment: @QingGuo, I added sample data to my Application and State table as per your request to show how the data in structured. As you can see, I'm using a single DropDownList for the Renters State (StateId) and if applicable the same StateId value from the single DropDownList that gets added to the AppTenantState field if their is a value that needs added to the AppTenantState field.

Comment: "and if applicable the same StateId value from the single DropDownList that gets added to the AppTenantState field" When do you add the StateId value into AppTenantState field? What do you mean about "if applicable"? And I am curious that why  your Sample Application Table Data StateId "33 ,38"  are not in  Sample State Table .@user18776105

Comment: @QingGuo, I decided to just create another DropDownList with a secondary States Table with different Fields. That resolved the issue.